# Resize Image within a Button

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there any way of resizing an image in a button? The image source is from the `drawables` folder. I want to have the following layout for the button.

[image]

I know that we can use the `android:drawableLeft` XML tag for the button, but the image is crossing the boundary of the button and thus getting cut off on all sides.

I want my **entire image** to be in within "Image here" slot from the above depicted layout. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a default button, use the default padding (don't set the padding values) and the image should not cross the boundary.

Alternatively for finer control you can place an ImageView and TextView within a layout (e.g. LinearLayout) and set the layout's `style="@android:style/Widget.Button"`.

Comment: I have not used any padding, I will try your alternative and let you know.